# Work around for m2e workspace resolution lacking test-classes in launcher classpath when test classifier set as dependency

Tags: eclipse, maven, junit, m2eclipse

Does anyone know how to workaround the problem where recent M2eclipse plugins fail to include dependent projects test-classes directory in junit launcher's classpath when the test's pom lists the test as a dependency?

Steps to Rep

- Create to pom projects   providerProj, userProj
- In providerProj create TestUtils class and store with its tests
- Set userProj to depend on provider's test classified artifact (provider-test.jar)
- Add userProj test which invokes TestUtils class from providerProj

On commandline all works as expected.  TestUtils class found via test classpath.

- Import projects into eclipse
- Run userProj test as junit

**failure** class not found.

When we check the classpath for the test don't see providerProj/test-classes folder.  If we close providerProj and rerun, it works and we see provider-test.jar on class path.

```
useProject
<dependency>
   <groupId>workspacetest</groupId>
   <artifactId>providerProj</artifactId>
   <classifier>test</classifier>
</dependency>
```

We can manually edit the launchers and add in the necessary folders but that's not ideal.  I might be able to convince m2eclipse to dump src and test output into target/classes which would mask the problem and open me up for entangled code.  I can fork m2eclipse and change handle to assume that test classifier dep means include workspace resolution target/test-classes.

Do you know of a solution to the problems?

Thanks

Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `<classifier>tests</classifier>`.

BTW, http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-attached-tests.html discourages the use of the tests classifier, `<type>test-jar</type>` is preferred.

Comment: Eclipse doesn't appear to handle classifiers at all.  I changed to tests and had the same problem.  It looks like eclipse m2e blanks out classifiers when handling workspace resolution.  Perhaps the non classifier route is the right approach and to use type

Comment: Aha, the m2eclipse folks must agree with the discouraging of tests classifier as well for when I switched from classifier to type my test class path was fixed.

Comment: No, the tests classifier works, I checked it. There must be something specific to your setup. Could you please report an issue at https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=m2e and attach a sample project depmonstrating the bug?

Comment: Using kepler and m2e it fails to add test classifier to classpath if and only if m2e uses workspace resolution.

Comment: However, I'm noticing that when I deploy test-jar to nexus maven uses classifier not type.  So, i'm very confused.  In local repo, <type>test-jar<type> can find the artifact but deploy isn't deploying what I expect.

Comment: Actually, that seems to be just how maven works.  The type test-jar translates into a classifier in the remote repository and back to a s type locally.  Very strange or a weird nexus bug perhaps.  It all works so that's the key part

Comment: test-jar only refers to the classes in main/test/java

Answer (score 2):

I wanted to do something similar not long ago.  The issue is that Eclipse and Maven handle builds differently, and right now Eclipse doesn't deal with Maven's concept of classified artifacts very well.  That's a paraphrase of notes I found in [this Eclipse bug report](http://jira.codehaus.org/browse/MNGECLIPSE-800).

I was able to find a workaround so both Eclipse and Maven function.  I add this to the POMs that need items from a classified jar.  (Note, I did this for test resources, not test source, so you may need to adjust if I don't have the config quite right below...)

```
<profile>
  <!-- Contents of this profile only needed to make this project work in Eclipse. -->
  <id>m2e</id>
  <activation>
    <property>
      <name>m2e.version</name>
    </property>
  </activation>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
        <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>include-test-source-eclipse</id>
            <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>add-test-source</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <sources>
                <source>../myOtherProj/src/test/java</source>
              </sources>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</profile>
```

Putting the build-helper plugin inside the profile ensures it only runs when in Eclipse, and not as part of a normal Maven build.  It isn't pretty, but it works, at least in Eclipse Juno and m2e 1.3.1.20130219-1424.

The only issue I've had with the configuration is that sometimes Eclipse doesn't seem to find changes I made in my provider project.  The fix is to run Maven --> Update Project on the provider project and any projects depending on it.  I wasn't changing resources often enough for this to be a big deal for me.

Comment: Where in the pom should this be? Not at root level, gets flagged up as an error (with no description) if put within the <project> tags. Thank you.

Comment: Old thread, but save anyone the trouble...  Surround `<profile>` with `<profiles>` as a child of `<project>`.  Don't forget to change the value of `<source>` to match your situation.